# Paypal IPN script not executing til the end

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm trying to write a script to update my database after the payment of the customer. My problem is that after the call of curl_init nothing seems to be happening...

My code is:

```
$pp_url = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
$ch = curl_init($pp_url);
```

As nothing was happening, I added some debug code in my log file, like that:

```
if ($ch === false) {
    addLog("Curl_init returned false");
}
else {
    addLog("Curl_init worked ok");
}
```

Problem: no message is displayed in my log file. 
I receive the log file content until these lines and then nothing.

Is there a way to understand what's going on ?
Because now I'm stuck, as I don't receive anything from Paypal...
So I'm not able to test weither or not the transaction went ok.

Please, I really need some help.

Thanks

Comment: First thing to do is to check the PayPal IPN History to see if it's sending notifications and what response it's getting back from your server.  If it's getting error responses then you could [follow these steps to test and troubleshoot IPN](https://www.angelleye.com/test-paypal-ipn/).

Answer (score 0):

How your addLog function is working?

You may try something that look like this:

```
// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Host: www.paypal.com\r\n";
$header .= "Connection: close\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
```

change the paypal.com adress to the sandbox one.
I never tried with curl, but it does work with fsockopen.

Comment: Thank you, it worked better, but res is never VERIFIED. Or I should say: it seems to be VERIFIED sometimes, but strcmp never returns 0...